# How to fix modules with "ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module" bailout message?

Tags: webpack, webpack-3

Webpack3 comes with the `ModuleConcatenation` plugin that when used with the `--display-optimization-bailout` flag will give you the reason for bailout.

The bailout messages not that easy to understand, and it's hard to understand why they happened to a specific module.

Here is my output for the `webpack` command on a very simplified version of my project:

```
> webpack --bail --display-optimization-bailout

Hash: 4a9a55dc2883e82a017e
Version: webpack 3.4.1
Child client:
    Hash: 4a9a55dc2883e82a017e
    Time: 594ms
                                   Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
        a.d3ade61d21d5cb8dd426.bundle.js  712 bytes       0  [emitted]         a
    a.d3ade61d21d5cb8dd426.bundle.js.map    6.57 kB       0  [emitted]         a
                           manifest.json  102 bytes          [emitted]         
                              index.html     299 kB          [emitted]  [big]  
       [0] multi ./src/client/bootstrap/ErrorTrap.js 28 bytes {0} [built]
           ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
       [1] ./src/client/bootstrap/ErrorTrap.js 199 bytes {0} [built]
           ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
```

I simplified the contents of `./src/client/bootstrap/ErrorTrap.js` as much as I could, and I still get the `ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module`. Here are its contents:

```
class ErrorTrap {
}

export default ErrorTrap;
```

I looked into understanding this bailout message, and one of the reasons it happens is when the module doesn't have imports or exports, as seen at https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/93ac8e9c3699bf704068eaccaceec57b3dd45a14/lib/dependencies/HarmonyDetectionParserPlugin.js#L12-L14, but I don't know why it's not considering this module a `ECMAScript` module.

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ]
}
```

**webpack.config.js** representation:

```
{ target: 'web',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: { a: [ './src/client/bootstrap/ErrorTrap.js' ] },
  output:
   { path: '/project/build/client/assets',
     filename: '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js',
     chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js',
     publicPath: '/assets/' },
  module: { rules: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] },
  resolve: { alias: { 'lodash.defaults': 'lodash' } },
  plugins:
   [ ModuleConcatenationPlugin { options: {} },
     CommonsChunkPlugin {
       chunkNames: [Object],
       filenameTemplate: undefined,
       minChunks: Infinity,
       selectedChunks: undefined,
       children: undefined,
       async: undefined,
       minSize: undefined,
       ident: '/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin.js0' },
     ManifestPlugin { opts: [Object] },
     ChunkManifestPlugin {
       manifestFilename: 'chunk-manifest.json',
       manifestVariable: 'webpackManifest',
       inlineManifest: false },
     OccurrenceOrderPlugin { preferEntry: undefined },
     DefinePlugin { definitions: [Object] },
     VisualizerPlugin { opts: [Object] },
     ExtractTextPlugin { filename: '[name].[contenthash].css', id: 1, options: {} },
     UglifyJsPlugin { options: [Object] },
     LoaderOptionsPlugin { options: [Object] } ],
  name: 'client' }
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're using Babel to transpile your JavaScript files and by default the `es2015` preset transforms ES modules (`import`/`export`) to CommonJS (what Node uses, `require`). Webpack receives the CommonJS modules, but the `ModuleConcatenationPlugin` relies on ES modules. You can configure Babel to not transform the modules with the [`modules` option](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/#optionsmodules).

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2015", { "modules": false }]
  ]
}
```

Webpack 2+ supports ES modules out of the box and it's best to leave them to webpack, because it enables features such as [Tree Shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/).

Comment: This seems to be where the problem is. I'll have to do more changes to make everything work but at least this gives me a path forward with optimized modules. Thank you very much!

Comment: I've done this and still get the bailout. I wonder if it's how my modules are structured.

Comment: @ScottLeonard did you add the option to your `webpack.config.js` or to your `.babelrc`? I found that it only works in the Webpack config.

Comment: When I try to add that to `webpack.config.js` I get `Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'presets'`. webpack version 4.44.2

Comment: 'presets' must be inside of the 'options' for the webpack babel loader

Answer (score 9):

For those who use modern `@babel/preset-env`:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env",{
      "targets": {
        ...
      },
      "modules": false
    }],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [...
}
```

But bad things (but not critical) that after that I can't use ES modules in my webpack config files as before, so in `webpack.config.babel.js`:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
```

should be changed to:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
```

Comment: Sadly this does not work for me. The error I get is:
```
Entrypoint mini-css-extract-plugin = *
    chunk    {0} * (mini-css-extract-plugin) 497 KiB [entry] [rendered]
        > !!/Us.....gin
     [0] ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--6-3!./source/scss/main.scss 495 KiB {0} [depth 0] [built]
         ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
         single entry !!/Use...ce/scss/main.scss  mini-css-extract-plugin
```

Answer (score 0):

I just recently faced a very similar issue with Ionic and Angular. I had imported a custom component into app.module.ts and then inserted it into entryComponents, later decided I wanted to go a different route. I removed the import and forgot the entryComponents entry. And I had the same error.

```
ModuleConcatenation bailout: Module is not an ECMAScript module
```

Then it pointed to my variable.scss path, followed by the following line

```
ERROR in Cannot read property 'members' of undefined
```

So to anyone with a similar issue (most probably using Ionic and or Angular), you might have to make sure you are not trying to use a component in a page where it's not actually imported, but still has a trailing point in the page.module.ts entryComponents.